# When using Sum() aggregate,how to show all other fields without group by in postresql?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have a simple example for reference firstly.

This is original sql:

```
string sql = @" SELECT po.*, c.abbr_name company_abbr_name FROM om_po po LEFT JOIN c_company c ON po.company_id=c.company_id WHERE TRUE";
```

Except this sql, I will also append some other where conditions according to the situation, such as:

```
sql += " AND po.po_id=@PoId";
sql += " AND c.company_abbr_name =@Name"
```

Due to multiple uncertain where conditions, I want to make these sql string more simpler, so I change the sql to :

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT po.*, c.abbr_name company_abbr_name FROM om_po po LEFT JOIN c_company c ON po.company_id=c.company_id) m  WHERE TRUE";
```

Now the where conditions can be changed like this:

```
 sql += " AND po_id=@PoId";
 sql += " AND company_abbr_name =@Name"
```

This avoids to add table alias(like **po.** **c.**) to fields in where conditions,so I can add these where conditions to this sql dynamically and uniformly through a common method.

The above example can be implemented successfully,however, I have another sql which contains **aggregate function** in it, and i have no idea how to avoid the table alias,here is my sql now:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT( 1 ) total_amount,
    SUM ( pl.qty ) total_qty,
    SUM ( pl.qty_received ) total_qty_received 
FROM
    om_po_line pl
    LEFT JOIN om_po P ON pl.po_id = P.po_id
    LEFT JOIN c_company C ON P.company_id = C.company_id 
WHERE
TRUE
```

And this sql's where condition contains the fields of **the three tables** inside(pl,P,C), so I cannot be able to put it to a new select sql:

```
Select * from (
SELECT 
        COUNT( 1 ) total_amount,
        SUM ( pl.qty ) total_qty,
        SUM ( pl.qty_received ) total_qty_received 
    FROM
        om_po_line pl
        LEFT JOIN om_po P ON pl.po_id = P.po_id
        LEFT JOIN c_company C ON P.company_id = C.company_id 

)
    WHERE
    TRUE
```

The above sql can not append my where conditions.

Please give some advice,or tell me if this idea is feasible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've read many times and I have no clue what you're trying to achieve or what your question could be. The title and the content don't seem even related.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: It **looks** like you are just trying to avoid table aliases, why I don't know. But then you can just defined a whole inner `select` with no aggregation, and aggregate on the outside

Comment: read about sql window functions

Comment: You are saying "*can not append my where conditions*", why do you think that? Do you get errors? if so what?  What is it you want to add?

Comment: Just my opinion, but `sql += " AND po_id=@PoId";` is not really simpler than `sql += " AND po.po_id=@PoId";`...  and the complexity you just added with the subquery would cancel out any simplicity you hoped to gain.  The alias itself does make the query more simple...  why do you want to avoid them?!?